# Double bar "|" in title (By WP SEO Yoast?)

Tags: title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am wondering why my pages (post doesn't have this problem) have a double bar "`|`" in them

eg. `About || Jiew Meng's Blog`

[image]

**UPDATE**

Actually it appears in other pages too, like [this](http://jiewmeng.phpfogapp.com/portfolio/klif-media-v2/). In this case, its a custom post type. Note the repeated site name

```
KLIF Media v2 |  | Jiew Meng&#039;s BlogJiew Meng&#039;s Blog
```

**UPDATE 2 (@CorvanNoorloos)**

Ok, I changed my title to

```
wp_title('')
```

Instead of the default `wp_title('|', true, 'right')` in TwentyTen. It fixed the double bar problem, but

If I go a Custom Post Type archive [link](http://jiewmeng.phpfogapp.com/portfolio/), I get something like

```
PortfolioJiew Meng's Blog
```

If I go a custom post type single page [link](http://jiewmeng.phpfogapp.com/portfolio/klif-media-v2/), I get

```
KLIF Media v2 - Jiew Men's BlogJiew Meng's Blog
```

If I force rewrite titles, it mostly works except for some pages, becoming

```
- Jiew Meng's Blog
```

I think I need to manually set the page title if I used this option?

Comment: Can't help you without any code.  Can I see the header.php file from this theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this plugin together with TwentyTen too and encountered the same problem.

My solution is to leave `wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );` unchanged but only enable the call to function `bloginfo()` in the next line if plugin WordPress SEO is inactive.

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// Add the blog name.
if ( is_plugin_inactive('wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php') ) {
    bloginfo( 'name' );  //this call conflicts with plugin "Wordpress SEO"
}
```

I don't use 'Force rewrite titles'. For the title templates I use `%%title%% | %%sitename%%`. For the homepage I've entered my custom title text.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by a theme you've installed (in this case a somewhat modified version of TwentyEleven).

Joost's plugin needs `<?php wp_title(''); ?>` in the `header.php`.

Have you tried to enable “Force rewrite titles”? (which is currently available at SEO -> Titles)

Comment: I did modified the code, but just minimally, and definitely not the title (I might have caused some side effects perhaps)

Comment: @jiewmeng AFAIK within TwentyEleven there's quite some code between the `<?php wp_title(''); ?> `single quotation marks. Have you tried removing it? What happened when you enabled the “Force rewrite titles”? Did it solve the issue?

Comment: OK I tried what you just mentioned in Update 2 in main question post. It mostly works with force rewrite titles, but that isn't the recommended way is it?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use the _empty_ `<?php wp_title('') ?>` (with nothing in between the single quotation marks) **AND** to use Joost's title settings instead of the default WordPress ones.